# Uncsoncious expectation of other people to be motivated by the same values as you

Tags: social-psychology, motivation, behavior, projection

Is there a special term describing the situation when somebody automatically expects other people's behaviour to be motivated by the same values that motivate his own?

For instance, out of my personal observations, dishonest people expect other people to be dishonest, as well. Dishonest people would never truly believe the behaviour of honest and loyal people around them. Much in the same manner, they would never truly abhor being cheated - to them that is something natural and while unpleasant, it is not necessarily evil - just like you would dislike bad weather, but you would not attribute the quality of evil to it.

Answer (score 2):

I think two close concepts are that of ["naïve realism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%C3%AFve_realism_(psychology)) and the [false consensus effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_consensus_effect).

The basic idea of naive realism is very simple. You believe your beliefs to be true! That seems a bit silly, but we can create a concrete example. Let's say you think President Trump is a great president. You have some reasons for believing it, and you have faith in your own cognitive abilities to judge evidence and come to logical conclusions. Therefore, if someone disagrees with your they must either have bad information or have different values (i.e. be bad people since most of us think of ourselves as good people).

The false consensus affect seems a bit closer to what you describe. That people (in this case, you) "overestimate the extent to which their opinions, beliefs, preferences, values, and habits are normal and typical of those of others (i.e., that others also think the same way that they do)"